# Link to a div but with margin

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, hyperlink

I am making a simple app using Slicknav jQuery plugin to make a mobile-friendly menu.

[Here][1] you can see the example.

There are four divs inside: home - second - third - fourth.

When I click on a link it goes properly to the menu.
But the title of the div is covered by the menu.
What I need to do is to link not exactly where the div begin but 50px up.
How can I do that? Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: it's common,Don't worry use padding or margin

Comment: Can you please post your code

Comment: The code is here: http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/7/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  .section{
  padding-top:50px; /*or you can use margin as well*/
    }


<div class="section" id="home"> … </div>
<div class="section" id="second"> … </div>
<div class="section" id="third"> … </div>
<div class="section" id="fourth"> … </div>
```

Your header

```
.slicknav_menu
```

is fixed part and it always hide anything coming user it. So you need to avoid thing coming under it. Use padding or margin

Comment: I have add a div as you say: http://jsbin.com/UqUloNO/10/edit
For the first section it works, but the others will go behing the menu bar. Where exactly i have to put the margin to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: You should give some space before each section

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <div id="home">
```

to

```
 <div id="home" style="margin-top:55px;">
```

do it inline, as you are using external style sheets.